# miniconda installed yarn - but yarn has only very old versions npm and nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, miniconda

Hi i wanted use miniconda to for small FARM project (FastApi, React and mongodb), and I want use yarn packet manager but i cannot upgrade nodejs and npm and this give me a little frustration

```
conda create --name wagalogitech python=3.9
conda activate cenv

#yarn has npm i nodejs
conda install -c conda-forge yarn

#check versions
pip --version
pip 21.2.4 from /home/matball/miniconda3/envs/wagalogitech/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
(wagalogitech) $ python --version
Python 3.9.7
(wagalogitech) $ yarn --version
1.22.17
(wagalogitech) $ npm --version
3.10.10
(wagalogitech) $ node --version
v6.13.1
```

I have tried a few times `yarn upgrade nodejs` but this not work - not update my packets... what i should do? I did that same thing at other computer a few days ago and ... that works ( i had nodejs v.16... where i do mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem was is in `conda install -c conda-forge yarn`

when i change that command for below, i have nodejs 16

`conda install yarn`